# Indexing a series in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below I have listed what my object countiespop returns as well as the type of the object. I cannot find a way to create a series of exclusively the 3 'STNAME'.

```
countiespop

Returns
STNAME
California    15924150
Texas          8269632
Illinois       6815061
Name: CENSUS2010POP, dtype: int64
```

`type(countiespop)`

Returns
`pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: Thank you for the edit! this was my first post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
#create a series using the index of the current Series
pd.Series(countiespop.index)
Out[274]: 
0    California
1         Texas
2      Illinois
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: I think your guess at interpreting OP is correct :-)

Comment: :-) Let's see. I might be totally wrong!

Comment: It's like being a goalie... you have to take a guess and go with it.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I was looking for. Everything I was doing was displaying the CENSUSPOP numbers.